# Keycloak - Show a message if a user is blocked

Tags: keycloak, wildfly-10

How can I show a message if a user is blocked after a brute force detection ?

I'm using [keycloak 2.0.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) and I keep having the same error "Invalid username or password."

Thanks

**UPDATE** : it seems like the issue has already been detected in the version 1.9.2.Final [HERE](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2799)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes It's available in the UserRepresentation returned by

[http://www.keycloak.org/docs/rest-api/index.html#_get_represenation_of_the_user](https://web.archive.org/web/20161222124230/http://www.keycloak.org:80/docs/rest-api/index.html#_get_represenation_of_the_user)

You can also check brute force status on

[http://www.keycloak.org/docs/rest-api/index.html#_get_status_of_a_username_in_brute_force_detection](https://web.archive.org/web/20161222124230/http://www.keycloak.org:80/docs/rest-api/index.html#_get_status_of_a_username_in_brute_force_detection)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't seen their API yet. Is it a new release ?

Comment: I don't know, I saw it from 2.1.0.Final version